# How to update List item with Managed Metadata column using REST or JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, splistitem, jsom, office-365-developer

How can i update List item with Managed Metadata column using REST or JSOM?
Any good sample or suggestion will be appriciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update managed metadata column, you need to get the associate termSet for the column and also get the term Id from that termset.

To update Managed Metadata column using `REST` check [this](http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/using-rest-to-update-a-managed-metadata-column-in-sharepoint)

Below is the code to add the item with managed metadata column using `JSOM`. Read Comments in code for more description.

```
jQuery(function($) {  
      var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "_layouts/15/";  
      $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",  
     function () {  
       $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){  
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", ExecuteTaxonomyFunctions);  
       });  
     }  
   );  
 });  
 function ExecuteTaxonomyFunctions()  
 {  
      var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
      var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Resources");  

      var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("ResourceType");  
      var txField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);  
      context.load(field);  
      context.load(txField);  
      //Get the response from server to get the termsetId  
      context.executeQueryAsync(function(){  
        //Get the term set ID  
           var termSetId = txField.get_termSetId().toString();  
           var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);  
           var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();  
           var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);  

           // Get the matching terms based on names  
           var lmi = new SP.Taxonomy.LabelMatchInformation(context);  
           lmi.set_lcid(1033);  
           lmi.set_trimUnavailable(true);  
           lmi.set_termLabel("UI Developer");  

           var termMatches = termSet.getTerms(lmi);  
           context.load(termMatches);  
           //Get the matching term and then add to list item  
           context.executeQueryAsync(function () {  
           if (termMatches && termMatches.get_count() > 0)  
           {  
               // Get the first matching term. As I know it has only one  
               // You need to iterate and get the correct term if you have same name terms  
               var term = termMatches.get_item(0);  

              // Add Item to list   
               var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
               var oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  
               oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Akash Karda');  
               var termFieldValue = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue();  
               termFieldValue.set_label(term.get_name());  
               termFieldValue.set_termGuid(term.get_id().toString());  
               termFieldValue.set_wssId(-1);  
               txField.setFieldValueByValue(oListItem, termFieldValue);  
               oListItem.update();       

               context.executeQueryAsync(function () {  
                 alert('Item Added');  
                }, function (sender, args) {  
                  alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
                });  

           }  
         }, function (sender, args) {  
            alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
         });  
      },function(sender,args){  
           alert(args.get_message());  
      });  
 }
```

**Reference :** http://akashkarda.blogspot.com/2014/06/adding-item-to-managed-metadata-column.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i resolved my case with updating an existing List Item with Managed Metadata Column using JSOM:

```
        function execRequest() {
        var taxPickerIndex = $("#taxPickerOpenSingle").val();
        var result = $.parseJSON(taxPickerIndex);
        var listTitle = "GNTiles";
        var taxFieldName = "Process";
        var termId = result[0].Id;
        var term = result[0].Name;
        console.log("Term ID: " + termId);
        console.log(result);

        var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var item = list.getItemById(tileId);

        var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Prosess");
        var txField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);

        context.load(field);
        context.load(txField);

        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            //Get the term set ID  
           // var termSetId = txField.get_termSetId().toString();
            var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
            var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
            var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);

            // Get the matching terms based on names  
            var lmi = new SP.Taxonomy.LabelMatchInformation(context);
            lmi.set_lcid(1033);
            lmi.set_trimUnavailable(true);
            lmi.set_termLabel("UI Developer");

            var termMatches = termSet.getTerms(lmi);
            context.load(termMatches);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {  
                var termFieldValue = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue();
                termFieldValue.set_label(term);
                termFieldValue.set_termGuid(termId);
                termFieldValue.set_wssId(-1);
                txField.setFieldValueByValue(item, termFieldValue);
                item.update();

                context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    console.log('Item Added');
                }, function (sender, args) {
                    console.log(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                });
             }, function (sender, args) {  
                console.log(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
             });

        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });

    }
```