# SharePoint Online JSOM Problems adding new item with Managed Metadata field

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, jsom, metadata

Hoping someone might be able to shed some light on a problem I'm having adding new items to a SharePoint Online list, using JSOM?

I have modified some code I found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187749/how-to-update-list-item-with-managed-metadata-column-using-rest-or-jsom) on stack exchange, the code works fine but, ONLY when I hard code the values I want in to the code. As soon as I try and use a variable that contains the values from the form, it fails with an unexpected error.

Can anyone offer any advice on why this is happening, please?

**The lines in questions are below, like this they work:**

```
lmi.set_termLabel('IT');  
oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Test');
```

**If I change them to the below they stop working:**

```
lmi.set_termLabel(txtTerm); 
oListItem.set_item('Title', txtTitle);
```

**Full code**

```
function ExecuteTaxonomyFunctions(txtTitle,txtTerm)  
     {  
          var siteUrl = '/sites/rob';


          var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);   
          var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("jQuery");  

          var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Dept");  
          var txField = context.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);  
          context.load(field);  
          context.load(txField);  
          //Get the response from server to get the termsetId  
          context.executeQueryAsync(function(){  
            //Get the term set ID  
               var termSetId = txField.get_termSetId().toString();  
               var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);  
               var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();  
               var termSet = termStore.getTermSet(termSetId);  

               // Get the matching terms based on names  
               var lmi = new SP.Taxonomy.LabelMatchInformation(context);  
               lmi.set_lcid(1033);  
               lmi.set_termLabel('IT'); //Variable used here will stop item from being created
               lmi.set_trimUnavailable(true);  


               var termMatches = termSet.getTerms(lmi);  
               context.load(termMatches);  
               //Get the matching term and then add to list item  
               context.executeQueryAsync(function () {  
               if (termMatches && termMatches.get_count() > 0)  
               {  
                   // Get the first matching term. As I know it has only one  
                   // You need to iterate and get the correct term if you have same name terms  
                   var term = termMatches.get_item(0);  

                  // Add Item to list   
                   var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
                   var oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  
                   oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Test');  //Variable used here will stop item from being created
                   var termFieldValue = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue();  
                   termFieldValue.set_label(term.get_name());  
                   termFieldValue.set_termGuid(term.get_id().toString());  
                   termFieldValue.set_wssId(-1);  
                   txField.setFieldValueByValue(oListItem, termFieldValue);  
                   oListItem.update();       

                   context.executeQueryAsync(function () {  
                     alert('Item Added');  
                    }, function (sender, args) {  
                      alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
                    });  

               }  
             }, function (sender, args) {  
                alert(args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
             });  
          },function(sender,args){  
               alert(args.get_message());  
          });  
     }
```

Comment: I'd show the codeblock in that ISNT working, not that is. Can you show where/how the `ExecuteTaxonomyFunctions` is being called?

Comment: Hi, this is the code block that isn't working. It does work when I hard code the values as shown in the first code section, but change it to use a variable  as shown in the second code section, and the whole thing fails.  See comments in 3rd code section: lmi.set_termLabel('IT'); //Variable used here will stop item from being created

Comment: technically, you have hardcoded the values in the code block above, stating it doesn't work when using a variable. How are you calling the function? There may be a disconnect or the data type of the variable is incorrect.